# Anonymous users in django many to many fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to make a simple blog in django. I have a django `ManyToManyField` in my models to keep the record of likes on a blog post. It is working just fine but it only allows authenticated users to like a post but not anonymous users. I also want anonymous users to be able to like a post. Is there a way to do it?

here is my models.py

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    post =  models.TextField(max_length=1500)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="post_likes")
```

here is my vies.py

```
def likes(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
       post = get_object_or_404(Posts, id=request.POST.get("like_button"))
       post.likes.add(request.user)
```

here `like_button` is a name of a input in form that has value=id of a post.

Comment: How would you track if the anonymous user has already liked something? There session would persist for only a limited amount of time so even if you save it some way it's not going to be very useful for them as well as for you as they can just spam likes if they keep cleaning cookies for your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion 1(inefficient): Use likes as an Integer field rather than a relationship between Posts and User.

```
Problem: that loses the logged-in users like info.
```

Suggestion 2:
first create one anonymous dummy user in your User database table.

then, perform the following:

```
if request.method == "POST":
       post = get_object_or_404(Posts, id=request.POST.get("like_button"))
       if request.user.is_authenticated:
           post.likes.add(request.user)
       else:
           dummyuser=User.objects.get(id=dummy_user_id)
           post.likes.add(dummyuser)
```

```
Problem: anonymous user can hit likes multiple times as you can't track them.
```